# How do I keep my well pump connections from leaking?

Tags: leak, well-pump

Well, I asked the question at the end of last season on which hoses to get.  The new Summer season is upon us and I've located some comparable hoses (could not find the exact ones mentioned, but found some with the same specs).  Having a super hard time getting them installed as they're so tight, but did finally get them on.  However, even with 2 worm gear hose clamps on each end, they leak.  Drips a little water while priming, and sucks air when pumping.  What's the trick to getting these things to seal?

Comment: Just to update on the end result.  For once I'm glad I gave up and had a pro come out.  :-)  He took care of all the damaged parts and swapped in a hard pipe for that section, complete with a disconnect and capping mechanism that will make Winter removal and storage much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/what-hoses-for-shallow-point-well/2394#2394) before:

> When you connect this pipe to the fittings, you'll need to heat it up (I prefer MEP gas but propane works as well) just enough so it can go on (you still need to apply a bit of force). If you heat it too much to the point it stretches, you'll weaken the pipe and probably cause a leak - if you do this, cut the end off and start over. Use two stainless steel gear clamps to ensure a reliable connection (you can usually get away with one -- but in an outside location like a well, an extra couple gear clamps is probably cheaper than the pain of having to do this repair again).

If it's leaking, then:

- You heated it up too much.
- There is something wrong with the barbed connector (eg, a cut through the barbs). Brass male adapters are usually better than PVC. I personally don't like nylon, nylon fittings seem to wear out really quickly after attaching/detaching just a couple times.

[image]

Comment: I'll try replacing the barbed connector and a fresh piece of hose.

Comment: Just a quick update.  I failed at replacing the barbed connectors.  Everything's all rusted together.  It's no longer a DIY project, I'm now hiring a professional to fix this mess.  :-)

Comment: Make sure that you (or whoever you hire) use brass or PVC parts when replacing. They won't rust, and you won't have that issue in the future. Nylon is cheap and so-so - personally I hate it because it's too soft, and is too easily damaged/stripped.